# Sum pivot table field on Eloquent many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have an `orders` table, an `items` table, and a pivot table called `item_order` which has two custom fields (`price`, `quantity`).  The relationship between `Order` and `Item` is belongsToMany.  I'm trying to return the count of all items with an id of `1`, where the parent `Order->status == 'received'`.  For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->withPivot('price', 'quantity');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('price', 'quantity');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean all the `orders` with the `status == 'received'` that contains that `item`?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the quantity ordered of a specific item where the `$order->status == 'received'`.  I know it has something to do with the sum of the pivot table `quantity` field, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Here's the latest failed attempt just to give you an idea where my mind is at:

`$items = Item::where('id', 1)
            ->whereHas('orders', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 'received');
            })
            ->selectRaw('item_order.amount as amount')
            ->sum('amount')->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$total_quantity = Item::find(1) // getting the Item
    ->orders() // entering the relationship
    ->with('items') // eager loading related data
    ->where('status', '=', 'received') // constraining the relationship
    ->get() // getting the results: Collection of Order
    ->sum('pivot.quantity'); // sum the pivot field to return a single value.
```

The strategy here is to find the desired `Item` to then get the related `Order`s to this `Item` that has a `'received'` status, to finally `sum` the pivot attribute in order to get a single value.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you know the `id` of the item, most performant way would be to query `item_order` table directly. I would create a [pivot model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) for `ItemOrder` and define the `belongsTo(Order::class)` relationship and do this:

```php
$sum = ItemOrder::where('item_id', $someItemId)
    ->whereHas('order', function ($q) {
        return $q->where('status', 'received');
    })
    ->sum('quantity');
```

Comment: I cannot get the Pivot Model to work correctly: **Call to undefined method App\ItemOrder::order()** I cannot find very good documentation on what exactly needs to be included on the pivot model. I did add the appropriate code on the `Item` and `Order` models:
`public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->using(ItemOrder::class)->as('orderedItem')->withPivot('price', 'quantity');
    }`

` public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)->using(ItemOrder::class)->as('orderedItem')->withPivot('price', 'quantity');
    }`